# Eclipse IDE can't proceed java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using eclipse 2020-03 and write a simple code here.

HelloWorld.java

```
public class HelloWorld{

  public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
  
  
}
```

However when I will try to execute it or click the play button on the designer, this will came out:

[image]

And if I try to select java application the run button is disabled.

Any suggestion/help TIA

Comment: Your Eclipse is a couple of releases and more than one year behind. Please upgrade. The screenshot shows a different file opened in the background than the `HelloWorld.java` of your question. Are there issues in the _Problems_ view?

Answer (score 0):

Just do what the window tells you to: "Press the 'New Configuration' button". It's.. the blank page with the plus sign in the corner, just as the window is showing you. THEN you can configure whatever you want. Alternatively, right click on any class file that has a `main` in it, and in the context menu, 'Debug' will show up. (There's almost no reason to even use run, debug gives you hot code replace and you can, well, debug, if you want to. If you set no breakpoints, you won't notice anything).